# Drools gets NullPointerException on rule outside of Agenda Filter

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, drools

I am working with Drools Engine and am getting an unexpected exception.

I keep receiving the exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.validator.controllers.Rule_When_health_notification_received_determine_system_status$u46$1878980533.eval0(Rule_When_health_notification_received_determine_system_status$u46$1878980533.java:8)
at com.validator.controllers.Rule_When_health_notification_received_determine_system_status$u46$1878980533Eval0InvokerGenerated.evaluate(Unknown Source)
at com.validator.controllers.Rule_When_health_notification_received_determine_system_status$u46$1878980533Eval0Invoker.evaluate(Unknown Source)
at org.drools.core.rule.EvalCondition.isAllowed(EvalCondition.java:118) [drools-core-6.3.0.Final.jar:6.3.0.Final]
```

The problem is that this rule should not be in my AgendaFilter.  The rules that should be running are:

```
FactHandle requestFact = kSession.insert(request);

kSession.fireAllRules(new GenericAgendaFilter(ObjectTypes.GROUP, Operations.ITEM_UPDATE));
```

Request Contains some basic information for the rule to use.

And the Tags my rule has are:

```
   @Type("ITEM")
   @Operation("CHANGE_HEALTH")
```

Any Idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any other context for this issue? Are these other Drools facts or other code involved in your project that relate to this?

Comment: I made a slight edit.  I also send in a request object that contains some information relevant to the given set of rules that are expected to run.  I am less interested in the exception and more confused as to why the rule is being checked in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `agenda-group` is only used to group the rules that you want to be **executed** together. All of the rules in your Knowledge Base are still going to be evaluated when needed, no matter what `agenda-group` they belong to.

Hope it helps,

Comment: This helped out a lot.  I realized that my object I passed into the rule was missing a piece of information when certain agenda-groups were called causing the null pointer exception.  I will make sure to make my rules a bit safer from now on.

Comment: Hello guys,
Is there any way to setup Drools execution algorithm in a manner that it just skips rules which throw null pointer exceptions, and to continue with evaluating next rules present in the Knowledge Base?
Since my data inserted into each KieSession that I create for sure will not satisfy every possible condition in every possible rule. I would want to prevent breaking rules evaluating after first null pointer exception.
Thank you in advance.